# How to explain your future goals in an evaluation interview?

Tags: politeness, explaining

I've thought about this for a while but don't really know how to go about this.
Our company just got merged with a bigger market player. However this opens up a whole lot of opportunities towards growth in the firm. This big merge is going to take place in just a few months. There are going to be individual interviews with everyone from our relatively small company about what they expect from the change and their goals associated with that.

I kind of know where I want to end up, yet I'm not entirely sure because I am still relatively young. I also don't really know what to expect exactly from this merge. Though I think this will turn out positively, I want to play my cards smart.

This brings us to this very important evaluation interview with the people from the new company. I would like to explain my goals. Yet don't want to sound too cocky. Or be seen as a "dreamer". I would like to step up my game but I'm not sure to what lengths I can go because I am still very young. I don't want my age to be a turn down, or to even backfire for me.

If anybody has some good suggestions on what to expect or what mindset to assume, what should be asked and what should be left out. Let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working in technology makes it easy, kind of.  Technology changes quickly and as old techs die, new ones rise to take their place.  So, if someone asks me where I want to be in 5 years, my response is "It's hard to see into the future that far.  My job didn't exist 5 years ago.  My plan is to continue to keep abreast of new developments in the field and determine where my skills and talents meet with these new developments.  Here's how I've done that in the past..."  On the flip side, however, if someone in technology doesn't want to constantly learn, you have about 5 years until your skills become obsolete.

For something like this, I'd suggest determining what you are excellent at and what you enjoy doing.  What can benefit the company over the long haul?  Where can I make the most impact? Keep in mind that things change.  Life goals change.  Interests change.  It's OK to say "I find myself interested in..."

As for mindset, I think a mindset of enthusiasm and excitement about what's coming is always a good thing.  How committed to being excellent are you?  What role can you play in the company's growth and profitability? How can you make your boss' job easier?  How independently can you work?  Where do you see opportunity now that didn't exist before?

As for what to ask: what changes will happen?  what opportunities do you see existing?  How will the company change?  WRT what to leave out: anything personal.  Don't talk about your hobbies, politics, religion, place of birth, etc.  No matter how much someone may ask, don't complain about the small company you work for.  Leave any negativity back home; this is the time to impress people and you do that by being positive, intellectually curious, and industrious.

Comment: Hi, @baldPrussian
Thank you for the quick response! Ill take in your advice. I'm very enthusiastic about what's coming. The oppertunity I see here is that there is room for much greater steps in a shorter period than before. There are some really good things to concider in your answer. Especially what NOT to talk about. It is indeed hard to say where you will see yourself in 5+ years. However i can set out some goals to achieve in those 5 years. But as you suggested. I will talk about this in the: "I'm interested in.." way. This is a first for me. So i figured I want to be prepared for it.